# Oro - assets building times out

Tags: orocommerce

We have problems building assets for oro version 4.x. Oro installation works fine and during installation it also succesfully builds assets (webpack). We have CICD pipeline and after every commit, we run following commands:

```
# Run composer install
composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-dev -vvv

# Remove cache
rm -rf /var/www/var/cache
php bin/console cache:warmup --no-interaction --env=prod -vvv

# Switch Oro to maintenance mode
php bin/console lexik:maintenance:lock --env=prod --no-interaction -vvv

# Set permissions
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/var

# Run migrations (first schema changes then fixtures)
php bin/console oro:migration:load --force --no-interaction -vvv
php bin/console oro:migration:data:load --no-interaction -vvv
php bin/console oro:migrations:data:storeroom:load --fixtures-type=storeroom

# Pricing recalculation
php bin/console oro:price-lists:recalculate --all

# Build assets
php bin/console oro:assets:install --env=prod --no-interaction -vvv

# Remove cache
rm -rf /var/www/var/cache
php bin/console cache:warmup --no-interaction --env=prod -vvv
```

It fails during "php bin/console oro:assets:install --env=prod --no-interaction -vvv", because of the timeout. It does not matter how much memory or cpu we allocate, or if we give it more time... It can consume 8gb memory and all CPU-s and keeps running for more than half an hour, it is then killed because of the timeout. During install this same command, takes about 2min to finish... What are we doing wrong?

EDIT: Increasing timeout does not help, it never finishes (we tried for an hour).

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the build timeout for webpack build from `config/config.yml` file in the application.

```
oro_asset:
    build_timeout: 1000
```

For more details, please check documentation on [OroAssetBundle](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/bundles/platform/AssetBundle/#build-timeout).

Comment: As I said, increasing timeout does not help. We tried running it for almost an hour and it did not finish. But during installation, asset building took only about 2min. But if I run it the second time it never completes.